# How to back from the activity without button

Tags: java, android

When I was browsing the slack application I found new feature I liked, which is the return of activity by dragging without pressing the back button as usual.

So is there a specific code to do that? I did a research on how to do that but I couldn't find any explanation for it, so how can I do that.

**Here is a short video about the new feature**
[click here](https://media.giphy.com/media/LrFBtzgZgbBpNYTMn4/giphy.gif)

Comment: IMO, This can be a navigation drawer on both sides ( DrawerLayout).
and handling open & close on based on swipe left & right gesture.

Comment: Yep, also this can be another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Thanks to **Coding in flow** for that. Watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci5146VOyg4) for more explanation.

## **Follow these steps to do the job.**

**1-** We will use a library to do that called [Slidr](https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr), use the last version.

```
// swipe the Activity to close
implementation 'com.r0adkll:slidableactivity:2.1.0'
```

**2-** Add a new style in your `styles.xml` called **SliderActivityTheme**.
This theme will make the background for the activity when swipe it as transparent to show the content of the fragment...etc, "default background white"

```
<!--Theme for Slider Activity-->
<style name="AppTheme.SliderActivityTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**3-** A- Add slide method to your `class` and called in `OnCreate`

```
// Make slider on the Activity
public void Slider () {
    Slidr.attach(this);
}
```

B- Called in `OnCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_name_here);

    // slider the activity
    Slider();
}
```

or just simply add this in your `OnCreate` directly

```
// slider the activity
Slidr.attach(this);
```

**4-** In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add the theme that we had to create.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SliderActivityTheme"
```

Make it like that

```
<activity
   android:name=".Activity.ActivityImages.ImagesMorningActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleTop"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SliderActivityTheme"/>
<activity
```

**That's all, and enjoy with your new feature ;)**

## Working with Fragment? No problem, check the [library](https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr) page to know how to do that